# Guitar playing Nothing else matters

Tags: guitar

As a beginner guitarist, I started learning Nothing else matters, but I have a problem: I can't hit the 3rd & 4th strings on the 5th fret and the 1st string on the 2nd fret at the same time, due to typle of my left hand and fingers. Can I hit the 3rd & 4th strings on the 4th fret and 1st string on the 2nd fret?

Answer (score 3):

If you hit the 4th fret on the 3rd and 4th strings, instead of hitting the 5th fret, it won't be the same. You would play different notes. What you can try doing is to play open strings instead of the 5th fret and see how that works out.