# Melody question

Tags: guitar

Can I hit 4th fret on the (B and G)strings and pull of high E string on the 2  fret at the same time instead of 5th fret and pull of high E string on the 2  fret at the same time in Nothing else matters due to my short left fingers...

Comment: Right now, this question isn't making a lot of sense. Pull of =pull-off? Hit = hammer-on? It's not clear.

Comment: I'm calling for the OP to make this question more clear.

Comment: [You have already asked this](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/37510/guitar-playing-nothing-else-matters/37512)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to play the 4th fret on the B and G strings and the 2nd on the E string instead of the 5th fret on the B and G strings and the 2nd fret on the E string? If so then no, you can't do this, because you'd be playing B,D#,F# instead of C,E,F#, and these are obviously different notes. If I've misread your query please do tell me.